# How to compile the objective c in windows using GNUstep

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am new to this iPhone. So I installed the GNUstep compiler and I imported one small program. Now I want to compile this and execute the code... I did this by using the code:

```
gcc -o hello hello.m -I/c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers \
-L /c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base \
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

but it is giving the error as

```
1./GNUstep/GNUstep/system/library/libraries:permission denied
2.ld.exe : cannot find -lobjc
3.ld.exe : cannot find -lgnustep-base-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString 
collect2:id returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me anyone.. have I too add any new libraries to this?

Comment: iOS development on Windows with GNUStep? Good luck is what I wish you. :)

Comment: will it work on windows or not using GNUstep? from google i got that we can run using GNUstep......

Comment: Yeah but GNUStep is really not something you can develop iPhone apps with. Buy a Mac first, install Xcode Developer Tools and then you can start developing iPhone apps. You'll need to be able to compile for ARM in the first place.

Comment: ok i am not developing any application in GNUstep,but try to run sample objective c program... can i run small small program in this?if so please send me the compilation code to compile the sample program...

Comment: Please help me in this ? now i am getting foundation.h no such files or directives are found... please help me... how can i get the foundation.h files in GNUstep compiler... please reply me any body nows it...

Comment: If iPhone is your target, you should consider switching from gcc to clang which fully supports the newer dialect and spare your partitions or use external storage device for GNU/Linux or FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o hello hello.m -L C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/Syst
em/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple check out my you tube tutorial about that : [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXFdMGcboNg)

Answer (score 0):

I use GNUstep GORM to make a Objective-C project. The GORM will make a GNUmakefile automatically. If you want to command line style for compile the project, open Shell (you may close the GORM), change to the project directory using cd command, and type make. The GNUstep will compile the project (followed the GNUmakefile). There is a simple project by Yen-Ju Chen at http://www.nongnu.org/gstutorial/en/ch10.html.